# Can you delete evt files in DB2DETAILDEADLOCK?

Tags: events, db2, db2-luw

In my IBM DB2 server (it is linux server) I have a problem that db2/db2_1 is 100% used. In this directory I see that in path "/db2/db2_1/db2inst1/NODE0000/SQL00001/db2event/db2detaildeadlock" are a lot of XXXX.evt files that takes some amount of disk space.

```
linuxprod:/db2/db2_1/db2inst1/NODE0000/SQL00001/db2event/db2detaildeadlock> ll
   -rw-r--r-- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1   2096934 2010-01-11 07:17 00000000.evt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1   2089026 2011-12-12 07:12 00000001.evt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1   2091422 2012-02-06 06:43 00000002.evt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1   2088934 2012-06-04 07:06 00000003.evt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1   1662969 2013-03-21 15:54 00000004.evt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1   1950082 2014-06-26 13:28 00000005.evt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1   2069150 2015-02-19 13:24 00000006.evt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1    203704 2015-04-14 16:30 00000007.evt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1 131061876 2015-04-14 16:30 00000008.evt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1    873559 2015-04-20 15:29 00000009.evt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1 129650884 2015-04-20 15:29 00000010.evt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1    371426 2015-07-07 15:10 00000011.evt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1 154020299 2015-07-07 15:10 00000012.evt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1    385652 2015-09-01 18:03 00000013.evt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1 150405814 2015-09-01 18:03 00000014.evt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1   2011825 2017-03-01 08:11 00000015.evt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1 129911624 2017-03-01 08:11 00000016.evt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1   1969859 2018-06-27 15:00 00000017.evt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1   2083040 2019-07-04 09:04 00000018.evt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1    765463 2019-09-16 16:54 00000019.evt
   -rw-r----- 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1        43 2019-07-04 09:04 db2event.ctl
```

Is it ok to delete this .evt files (or move them to some other disk)? What happens if I delete them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to delete older event files. Since you don't seem to be using this event monitor anyway, you might as well disable it:

```
set event monitor DB2DETAILDEADLOCK state 0
```

The deadlock event monitor is [deprecated since Db2 9.7](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/i0054715.html), so you probably should consider dropping it altogether and creating a new event monitor for locks, which collects more useful information.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can erase  these .evt files, but the consequence is that you (or any DBA) will not then be able to investigate those deadlock / timeout events (unless they are reproducible).

You can also move them to another location for later inspection via the relevant tooling, this is possibly the safest option for a production system.

It's likely that these files are not the main user of the space in that file system, so be sure to eliminate (or control) the main space consumers first.

Perhaps you should consider investigating and resolving the events that are leading to the deadlocks/timeouts?

The relevant event-monitor that creates these files can also be disabled, and the size and number of the files can be controlled via configuration. Refer to the Db2 Knowledge centre for details of this configuration activity.